# Dark spots at intersection of volumetric spotlights

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, volumetrics

I have a bunch of volumetric spotlights in my scene. These are Spot Lamps parented to cones with a Principled Volume material. When several of these lights shine at the same spot or when one light shines through the cone of another, I get these artifacts that flicker from frame to frame. It almost looks as if the lights are interfering with one another. What does this mean? My memory usage is way below capacity.[image: A school gym set up for an event with bleachers on the sides, jumbotrons at the end, and red spotlights mounted on the ceiling. A thick fog envelops the room]

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out what was causing the issue. It was in fact the intersection of multiple volumetric objects. While I thought at first that using haze only on the actual spotlights would be more render-economical, turns out it creates issues and takes longer to render than if the entire scene is filled with a fog cube.